# How to use Css and Html in android?

Tags: android, css

I am beginner for android app development. I developed some app in android but now i want to use my own CSS styles in my app. I don't know how to use css in android can any one help me  how to use CSS? and give some tutorial for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use java-script enabled webviews.

reference:- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: how to enable webviews could you tell me?

Comment: we have control in toolbox called webview. try this http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: I think this tutorial will help you...http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Comment: You are always welcome...please up-vote and accept the answer so others can refer it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply only for enabled webview.refer this [link](http://androidsir.blogspot.in/2012/12/javascript-example-in-android.html).Use webview component in your activity.put your html in assets folder in your project.